# Flutter compass example

Tags: flutter, dart, location, compass, direction

I hope everyone is doing well. I am using flutter (as a beginner), and I want to create a simple compass app. I installed flutter_compass and used the example provided by the package to test it, but it stuck on infinite loading. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Note: I noticed that the code stuck on `connectState == wating`.

[Full code](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_compass/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

[The example link](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_compass).

```
  Widget _buildCompass() {
    return StreamBuilder<CompassEvent>(
      stream: FlutterCompass.events,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error reading heading: ${snapshot.error}');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        double? direction = snapshot.data!.heading;

        // if direction is null, then device does not support this sensor
        // show error message
        if (direction == null)
          return Center(
            child: Text("Device does not have sensors !"),
          );

        return Material(
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: (direction * (math.pi / 180) * -1),
              child: Image.asset('assets/compass.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

i just learned that u can't use flutter compass package on IOS simulator because it doesn't have the sensor that required for the package to work properly that is why it's stuck on infinite loading screen(connectState == waiting), so you just have to test it in a real Iphone device and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did u update your android manifest file yet ?

> iOS Make sure to add keys with appropriate descriptions to the
> Info.plist file.
>
> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
> NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription  Reference example code
>
> Android Make sure to add permissions to the
> app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file.
>
> android.permission.INTERNET android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION